# Does this particular L-series built from L-functions of prime degree define an L-function?

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms, l-functions, selberg-class

Throughout this question, I call 'L-function' any automorphic L-function belonging to the Selberg class.

Suppose  $ (F_i)_{(i>0)} $ is a sequence of L-functions with  $ F_i $ of degree  $ p_i $ for all  $ i $ and let  $ a_{p_{i}} $ be the  $ p_i$ -th coefficient of the L-series defining  $ F_i $ .

Does the sequence  $ a_{p_i} $ define an L-function ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surely not.

First, you can't just patch things together at random to get an $L$-function.

Second, your "construction" doesn't limit the growth of the $a_{p_i}$'s, so they need not satisfy Ramanujan.